# ActionText Trix Editor rails 7.0.7 won't load in production environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, trix, actiontext

I've created an action text editor with a rails 7.0.7 app, ruby 3.2.2 . The action text for works fine in development but it won't load in production. When I open up the dev tools it can't find trix sheet in either production or development:

`404 not found mysite.com/assets/trix/dist/trix`

But the editor works fine in development. I'm using Capistrano to deploy the app to an Ubuntu server and it is automatically pre-compiling my assets. How do I get action text to work in a rails 7 production environment?

The `<%= javascript_importmap_tags %>` is not loading fast enough in the production environment. Via the web development console I am getting this error:

```
The resource at “https://example.com/assets/application-
1f9c638bad3431a2e119d5da3d19e833a518370510fc773f111900f8393e0d7f.css” 
preloaded with link preload was not used within a few seconds. Make 
sure all attributes of the preload tag are set correctly.
```

`app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`

```
 <%= javascript_importmap_tags %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "actiontext", "data-turbo-track": "reload" %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "tailwind", "inter-font", "data-turbo-track": "reload" %>
    
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", "data-turbo-track": "reload" %>
```

`action_text.css`

```
/*

 *= require trix
*/

/*
 * We need to override trix.css’s image gallery styles to accommodate the
 * <action-text-attachment> element we wrap around attachments. Otherwise,
 * images in galleries will be squished by the max-width: 33%; rule.
*/
.trix-content .attachment-gallery > action-text-attachment,
.trix-content .attachment-gallery > .attachment {
  flex: 1 0 33%;
  padding: 0 0.5em;
  max-width: 33%;
}

.trix-content .attachment-gallery.attachment-gallery--2 > action-text-attachment,
.trix-content .attachment-gallery.attachment-gallery--2 > .attachment, .trix-content .attachment-gallery.attachment-gallery--4 > action-text-attachment,
.trix-content .attachment-gallery.attachment-gallery--4 > .attachment {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  max-width: 50%;
}

.trix-content action-text-attachment .attachment {
  padding: 0 !important;
  max-width: 100% !important;
}
```

`application.css`

```
@import "./actiontext.css";
@import "trix/dist/trix";
```

`manifest.js`

```
//= link actiontext.css
//= link_tree ../images
//= link_directory ../stylesheets .css
//= link_tree ../../javascript .js
//= link_tree ../../../vendor/javascript .js
// application.js
// youtube.js
```

`javascript/application.js`

```
import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"
import "controllers"
import "trix"
import "@rails/actiontext"
import "./youtube" 
import "@rails/ujs"
import "rails"
```

When I removed the `<%= javascript_importmap_tags %>` in the development environment the text editor looks the same as it does in production. Here is what it looks like:
[image: Trix Not Rendering properly in production environment]

Comment: are you using importmaps? don't use relative imports. otherwise, it's hard to tell just from the error: `trix/dist/trix` is not a digested url. undigested assets don't work in production (usually) but they do work in development.

Comment: I am using importmaps.I had to pin a couple things manually in development, should I do this in production as well? How should I use a digested `trix/dist/trix` asset?

Comment: the trix not found error also appears in development but like I said, the editor works fine there.

Comment: "javascript_importmap_tags" - is for javascript, the Warning that you're showing is for css and doesn't affect anything. you need to update your question with the details of your set up.

Comment: OK, thanks for taking the time to help. Sorry for the confusion, I didn't know if the CSS error was what was causing the Trix Editor to not render so I left it in. My setup is vanilla I just ran `rails action_text:install`, but I'm going to add the relevant files to the question right now.

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```rb
# config/importmap.rb

pin "trix"
pin "@rails/actiontext", to: "actiontext.js"
```

```js
// app/javascript/application.js

import "trix"
import "@rails/actiontext"
```

You should have a generated `actiontext.css` in `app/assets/stylesheets`:

```rb
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "actiontext", "data-turbo-track": "reload" %>
```

Remove any other references to trix and actiontext.

---

**Update**

That last ^ sentence, I really meant it, you don't need anything else.

This part from `actiontext.css` (or is it `action_text.css`) isn't going to work. It could work in development if tailwind is not minifying assets. In production, minification should be on, and that `sprockets` directive is stripped by tailwind before it can get to sprockets.

```css
*= require trix
```

That's why I always do `stylesheet_link_tag "actiontext"` and do not import it in my application.css.

```scss
// you don't need to import this one it is already in stylesheet_link_tag
@import "./actiontext.css";
// don't need that either since you don't have that file
@import "trix/dist/trix";
```

Also, a little fix for your stylesheets. Does your application.css get compiled by tailwind? Then you don't need to add it to stylesheet_link_tag:

```rb
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "tailwind", "actiontext", "inter-font", "data-turbo-track": "reload" %>
```

You seem to be missing builds directory as well in manifest.js, otherwise, I don't know where would "tailwind" stylesheet come from:

```js
//= link_tree ../builds
```

"//= link actiontext.css" is not needed.

---

`import "./youtube"` - no no. don't do relative imports it will break in production.

---

*https://github.com/rails/sprockets#directives*

Comment: I already have all of this.

Comment: @CJG ok, just take out where "trix/dist/trix" is coming from and you're good to go.

Comment: That didn't work. Trix works fine in development but not the production environment, I'm not sure you're understanding the quest. My trix asset loads fine, it has a hashed value on the production site.

Comment: All other trix classes work except for the text editor in the production environment.

Comment: @CJG see update. not sure if that will fix everything for you. you should really clean a few things up first.

Comment: Thank you for your help, none of this working. I don't know what I did, I've looked through my commit history to points where trix was working and tried to go back there but it still doesn't work. I'm just going to start a new application and copy everything over. Thanks

Comment: OK I got it to load without having to start over the project thank god!! I had to remove the `import "rails"` from `/javascript/application.js`

Comment: @CJG great. did you have a pin for "rails"? with importmaps you can only import things that have a pin/importmap, see `bin/importmap json` to know what you can import. although, I would've expected it to behave the same in production and development.